# slow iframe loading on website

Tags: php, html, iframe

I have tried to search for this but either I don't know the right search terms or there is no answer.

I have a site that I have made for online ordering. The cart that I made is in its own iframe, mainly as i didn't want the whole page to reload just the cart once something was added or removed etc.

The issue is the cart loads very slowly, at least at first or if pressing refresh. Its almost like it loads after the page is done loading. Is there a way to fix that?

the page for reference is http://www.nomadcss.com.au/posweb

Comment: You shouldn't be using frames in the first place :|

Comment: this is a very general question, you should do more research about it before coming to SO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iframes will load after other page elements because they are often referencing content on a completely different server. However in this case it could be your browser or your internet connection. When I tested the page referenced, everything loaded very quickly. I was able to add and remove things from the cart, opening and closing the iframe, with no lag whatever.